# pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

I have this code. But it has error when the code reaches if statement.

```
for x in range(50):
    element = app.Dialog.child_window(title="test123", control_type="Text")
    app.Dialog.child_window(auto_id="uxEntityDataGrid").wrapper_object().scroll("down", "line", count=5,
                                                                                retry_interval=0.01)
    try:
        if element.is_visible():
            print("Element is Visible")
            element.click_input()
            break
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

Basically my scenario is to click the element and break the loop once found. Unable to find similar topic so Im reaching to you experts out there. Many Thanks!

Traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 250, in __resolve_control
    ctrl = wait_until_passes(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\get object project\ObjectIdentification.py", line 37, in <module>
    raise e
  File "D:\get object project\ObjectIdentification.py", line 33, in <module>
    if element.is_visible():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 379, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 261, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 222, in __get_ctrl
    ctrl = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**ctrl_criteria))
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'test123', 'control_type': 'Text', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'Merlot.Aero', Window, 1444560>, 'backend': 'uia'}

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need `.exists(timeout=5)` method first. `.is_visible()` method is applicable to existing elements only. Method `.exists()` doesn't raise an exception but returns `bool` value.

If you need more details on timing issues and available methods, look at this guide: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html